# Correct location for questions covering multiple fields

Tags: discussion, questions, low-quality-posts, stack-exchange, forums

If a question clearly covers both programming and another field like thermal physics, electrical engineering, linguistics, mathematics, etc. may it then be posted on Stack Overflow?

According to the website guidelines questions that cover:

- a specific programming problem, or
- a software algorithm, or
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

are suitable for the website.

Here are some examples of topics which I would not know if they are suitable to post on the site:

- low-energy encoding algorithms
- development of an encryption algorithm
- semantic differences between programming and other languages
- programming problem related to underlying hardware

Also I want to mention that this is not a case study, but more a principal question about the nature of Stack Overflow.

Comment: A bit off topic, but I gotta say I love your name :D

Comment: As long as the *heart* of  the question is related to programming (rather than, say, a formula or an issue from physics or whatever), it's likely to be   fine on SO.

Comment: I agree with you, Pekka 웃, but the essence of the question is if both fields truly are at the heart of a question, is it still suitable to be posted on SO?

Comment: A relevant case is also when a user doesn't know in advance if solution to a problem lies closer to software or another field. Does the question still belong at SO if the answers reveal that the heart of the problem lies in another field.